# Inequality about two inner product?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Proving the inequality below.

Based on $ i \neq \tilde{i} $, for all $k$, we have the inequality that:

$
\langle P_{i\cdot},P_{k\cdot}\rangle - \langle P_{\tilde{i}\cdot},P_{k\cdot}\rangle \le \|P_{i\cdot}-P_{\tilde{i}\cdot}\|_2\ \|P_{k\cdot}\|_2
$

where $P_{i\cdot}$ means the $i$ row of the matrix $P$.

Can anyone help me on this, I have no clue to prove it.

Comment: Use Cauchy Schwarz with $P_i-P_{\tilde{i}}$ and $P_k$.

Comment: Thank you for your help